# Spring ContollerAdvice does not add body to returned error

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, httprequest

I am new to spring and I am trying to figure out global exception handling. What I am trying to achieve here is when a request is made with an unexisting primary key, I want to return an HTTP_NO_CONTENT with the body including timestamp and given id of the said request.

Here is my Controller Advice

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ControllerAdvisor {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoLevelFoundException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> handleNoLevelFoundException( NoLevelFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

        ResponseBody error = new ResponseBody();
        error.setTime(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
        error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

        return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

And these are my custom exception and respondBody

```
public class NoLevelFoundException extends RuntimeException{
    public NoLevelFoundException(int id) {
        super("No level with id " + id + " found!");
    }
}

public class ResponseBody {
    private Timestamp time;
    private String message;

    ...
}
```

When I make a request to an unexisting item via postman I receive this.
[image: Status code is right but body is empty]

With `return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();` I still get the right status code but I could not find any way to add body.

I also tried this piece of code

```
ResponseBody error = new ResponseBody();
error.setTime(Timestamp.from(Instant.now()));
error.setMessage(ex.getMessage());

return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).body(error);
```

With this style, I explicitly add body yet the outcome is still same. Right HTTP status but empty body.

#EDIT

This is how I  throw my error in the first place

first request is captured by RestContorller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/levels")
public class LevelRestApi {

    private ServiceLayer service;

    @Autowired
    public LevelRestApi(ServiceLayer service, LevelRepository repo) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @GetMapping("/{stage}")
    public Level getLevel(@PathVariable int stage){
        return service.getLevel(stage);
    }
}
```

calls service layer which checks if the item exists or not. I throw the error in here.

```
@Service
public class AlienInvadersServiceLayer implements ServiceLayer {

    JpaRepository levelRepository;

    @Autowired
    public AlienInvadersServiceLayer(@Qualifier(value = "levelRepository") JpaRepository levelRepository) {
        this.levelRepository = levelRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Level getLevel(int levelId) {
        Optional<Level> result = levelRepository.findById(levelId);
        if (result.isPresent()){
            return result.get();
        }
        else {
            throw new NoLevelFoundException(levelId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to throw execption using `NoLevelFoundException ` where ever you want `@ControllerAdvice` to handle error. Share code where you have handled `unexisting item`

Comment: Or else use `@RestControllerAdvice` instead of `@ControllerAdvice`

Comment: I tried both of them but it didn’t do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is with the `return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);`
of `handleNoLevelFoundException` method.

When you say `NO_CONTENT` it just empty your response body and does makes sense.
I would suggest use `HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND` instead.

So your code should looks like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(NoLevelFoundException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ResponseBody> handleNoLevelFoundException( NoLevelFoundException ex) {
    // other code
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

Comment: Thank you changing the status solved the problem. Do you think in this case NOT_FOUND is the best response because when I see NOT_FOUND it generally means wrong HTTP address.

Comment: Yes NOT_FOUND is right in your case. `HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT` is best suitable for `DELETE` request when you really does not expect in the response body.